# I need to update the 2 different <p>tag with the strings stored in 2 different arrays using single function

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I need to update the 2 different <p> tags with the stings stored in 2 different arrays using a single function.
The output I am getting is 'apple' 'bmw'. I need to change the content of the <p> tag in frequent interval of time.

```html
<div class="text">
    <p id="para1"></p>
    <p id="para2"></p>
</div>
<script>
    //array
    let para1_array = ['Apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'mango'];
    let para2_array = ['benz', 'bmw', 'tata', 'ford'];
    //getting element id
    const para1 = document.getElementById('para1');
    const para2 = document.getElementById('para2');
    let wordIndex = 0;
    //function
    function updateWord(para_array, para) {
        const currentWord = para_array[wordIndex];
        para.innerHTML = currentWord;
        wordIndex++;
        if (wordIndex >= para_array.length) {
            wordIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    //Function calling
    updateWord(para1_array, para1);
    updateWord(para2_array, para2);
    setInterval(updateWord,200)
   
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval(updateWord, 400);` - this will call `updateWord` with no values for the function parameters.

Comment: You need to pass a function into `setInterval` but not a function call: `setInterval(() => updateWord(para1_array,para1), 200)`

Comment: yes working ......

Answer (score 0):

Currently you call `updateWord` twice and then `setInteval` function is calling `updateWord` without any parameters.

If you want to call `updateWord` for both elements every 200 miliseconds this structure should work for you:

```
setInterval(() => {
    updateWord(para1_array, para1);
    updateWord(para2_array, para2);
},200);
```

Also your code seems buggy because you use the same index for both arrays, so one of them alternates between elements 0 ('Apple') and 2 ('melon') while the other alternates between elements 1 ('bmw') and 3 ('ford').
If you change your `updateWord` function to check the current index and increment it, your code will cycle through the whole array:

```
function updateWord(para_array, para) {
   let currentIndex = para_array.indexOf(para.innerHTML);
   currentIndex++;
   if (currentIndex >= para_array.length) {
       currentIndex = 0;
   }
   para.innerHTML = para_array[currentIndex];
}
```